# Are flushed objects returned from the database transaction buffer or from the in-memory representation in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to understand how SQLAlchemy works under the hood.

Consider the following example:

```
user.name  # ==> 'user1'
user.name = 'user2'
session.flush()
user.name  # ==> 'user2' (in-memory representation)
session.refresh(user)
user.name # ==> 'user2'
```

`session.refresh(user)` will force SQLAlchemy to update the `user` object immediately. Will SQLAlchemy actually execute a SQL query in this case? If so, will the database return data from its transaction buffer (flushed, but uncommitted data) or from the actual database record?

Comment: [Turn on logging](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#configuring-logging) and observe, it's a good way to get familiar with the internals in other cases as well. The latter question depends at least on your transaction isolation level.

Comment: What do you mean by transaction isolation level?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Isolation_levels describes the 4 standard SQL transaction isolation levels. As an example MySQL's default is REPEATABLE READ, so it reads data from the (possibly modified) snapshot established at the beginning of the transaction. PostgreSQL's default is READ COMMITTED.

Comment: By "snapshot" you mean "transaction buffer"? Do you know the default for transaction isolation level for MSSQL?

Comment: Seems to be READ COMMITTED ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

Comment: Why does that source only talk about modifications made by other transactions? My question is about whether the current transaction will read it's own snapshot data or not.